# What version of iOS is my iPhone capable of running?

Tags: iphone

I currently have iOS 6.1.6 on an iPhone 3GS. What is that the highest, *supported* version of iOS my iPhone is capable of running?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 6.1.6 is the highest supported iOS version you can install on an iPhone 3GS.

[Here is a handy iOS compatibility chart for iPhones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPhone) (and other iOS devices).